# In XSLT, why do I need to do comparisons with variables instead of with attribute values (in a test expression)

Tags: xslt

I am parsing a document, with different behavior depending on whether the id attribute is an element of a collection of values ($item-ids in the code below). My question is, why do I need to assign a variable and then compare with that value, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="word/item">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="@abg:id"/>
    <xsl:if test="$item-ids[.=$id]">
        <xsl:message>It matches!</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

It seems to be that I should be able to do it like this, though it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="word/item">
    <xsl:if test="$item-ids[.=@abg:id]">
        <xsl:message>It matches!</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This is something I keep forgetting and having to relearn. Can anybody explain why it works this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a variable in this case. Here you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="word/item">
    <xsl:if test="$item-ids[. = current()/@abg:id]">
        <xsl:message>It matches!</xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The reason you can't just use `$item-ids[. = @abg:id]` is that inside the `[]`, you are in the context of whatever is right before the `[]` (in this case `$item-ids`), so `@abg:id` would be treated as `$item-ids/@abg:id`, which isn't what you want.

`current()` refers to the current context *outside* of the `<xsl:if>` so `current()/@abg:id` should reflect you the value you want.

Answer (score 2):

To understand XPath, you need to understand the concept of the context node. An expression like @id is selecting an attribute of the context node. And the context node changes inside square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the line

```
<xsl:if test="$item-ids[.=@abg:id]">
```

compares the value of `$item-ids` to the string '@abg:id' - you need to compare it to the value of `@abg:id` which is why you need to select that value into the `$id` variable for the test to work.

Does that help at all?

Edit: I've misunderstood the issue - the other answers are better than mine.